# OLEDB - can't read excel sheet from powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, oledb

I'm trying to read data from excel (xls) sheet. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, Office 2007 (without access) and Visio 2010. I installed the `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 32-bit` (I tried installing 64-bit version, but installer said that I'm using 32-bit office so it can't install)  and the `2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components` and my connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$filePath`";Extended Properties=`"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES`";
```

But I'm getting error that provider `'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'` is not registered on local computer. Solutions I encountered where saying that project should be recompiled wit x86, but I', trying to do it from powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an x64 there are two Powershell hosts, an x64 and an x86. Have you tried running from the x86 host.